Problems sending data to my Arduino from Python using pySerial
I'm trying to send a '1' or a '0' to my Arduino in Python using pySerial so that from my Arduino I can read whatever the Python program sends and then turn a relay on and off depending on what it reads from Python.
Here is the Python code:
import cv2
import imutils
import threading
import time
import serial

Arduino = serial.Serial("COM7")
Arduino.baudrate = 9600

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

_, start_frame = cap.read()
start_frame = imutils.resize(start_frame, width=500)
start_frame = cv2.cvtColor(start_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
start_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(start_frame, (21, 21), 0)

alarm = False
alarmMode = False
alarmCounter = 0

def beep_alarm():
    global alarm
    for i in range(5):
        if not alarmMode:
            break
        print("HE MOVIN HE MOVIN")
        Arduino.write(str.encode("1"))
    alarm = False
    Arduino.write(str.encode("0"))

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    if alarmMode:
        frameBW = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frameBW = cv2.GaussianBlur(frameBW, (5, 5), 0)

        difference = cv2.absdiff(frameBW, start_frame)
        threshhold = cv2.threshold(difference, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        start_frame = frameBW

        if threshhold.sum() > 300:
            alarmCounter += 1
        else:
            if alarmCounter > 0:
                alarmCounter -= 1

        cv2.imshow("Cam", threshhold)
    else:
        cv2.imshow("Cam", frame)

    if alarmCounter > 20:
        if not alarm:
            alarm = True
            threading.Thread(target=beep_alarm).start()

    keypress = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if keypress == ord("t"):
        alarmMode = not alarmMode
        alarmCounter = 0
    if keypress == ord("q"):
        alarmMode = False
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

It's basically a movement detection program. If it detects me moving it should send a '1' to the Arduino where it then turns on a relay.
Here is the arduino code:
int relay = 11;
bool moving = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(1);
  pinMode(relay,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
}
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    if (Serial.read() > 0) {
      while (!Serial.available()) {
        if (moving == false) {
          digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
          delay(100);
          moving = true;
        } else {
          digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
          delay(100);
          moving = false;
        }
      }
    }
    digitalWrite(relay,LOW);
    delay(100);
  }
}


are you able to send data successfully using serial monitor?

You didn't specify, what the problem actually is, but I already see an error, that is probably the problem here.
You are sending the string "0" or the string "1" from python. This being a string - in contrast to a number in some binary format - means, that it is encoded as ASCII text. Have a look at an ASCII table, for example here. You will find the symbol/character "0" to have a decimal value (DEC) of 48. "1" is decimal 49.
On the Arduino side you have Serial.read() > 0. Serial.read() returns an integer, so a decimal number (or more specific a binary representation of it). So you got either 48 > 0 or 49 > 0, which is always true. Keep in mind the difference between ASCII encoding and binary integer encoding.
You can replace the above with
if(Serial.read() == '1'){

This tests, if you received the character (ASCII encoded!) '1' (the single quotes are for characters).
Note: It seems you want to switching the relay on and off until another character is send. Currently you are switching the relay 10 times a second. That is much for a relay, especially, if you are switching high voltages (like mains power). You should be aware, that this might cause problems with your relay after some time.
